# Получить один массив из объекта массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы, obj

Помогите пожста разобраться со следующей конструкцией. Есть объект с массивами и в них содержаться объекты:

```
const rooms = {

    room1: [
        { name: 'Jack' },
        { name: 'Andrey' },
        { name: 'Ann' }
    ],
    room2: [
        { name: 'Vasya' },
        { name: 'Jon' },
    ],

    room3: [
        { name: 'Petro' },
        { name: 'Alex' },
    ]
};
```

Нужно получить массив имен с помощью функции(при этом использую только методы объектов и массивов, не использовать по возможности цикл for):

```
console.log(getPeople(rooms));

// Output: ['Jack', 'Andrey', 'Ann', 'Vasya', 'Jon', 'Petro', 'Alex']
```

Начал делать и пытался, но получалась ерунда. Если можно, то направить как решить задачу, подсказать хоть как-то с чего начать в целом:

```
const getPeople = obj => {

    const arr = Object.values(obj);

    return ;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете просто взять все значения как массив и применить к нему [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const rooms = {
    room1: [
        { name: 'Jack' },
        { name: 'Andrey' },
        { name: 'Ann' }
    ],
    room2: [
        { name: 'Vasya' },
        { name: 'Jon' },
    ],

    room3: [
        { name: 'Petro' },
        { name: 'Alex' },
    ]
};


const getOneArr = (obj) => Object.values(obj).flat();

console.log(getOneArr(rooms));
```

Comment: точно, метод flat() - я забыл про него. Спасибо, далее проще уже

Comment: Обращайтесь! Не забываем благодарить галочкой и/или голосом за :)